# Can AutoQuery return a single item (not list)

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-autoquery

When I add a type to AutoQuery, with:

```cs
[Route("/templates")]
public class SearchTemplates : QueryDb<Template>
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

then I can query this object by Id or Name (or whatever other attributes I would add, that the POCO Template has). However it always returns list of items.

It's very useful to be able to GET a single item (not a search result).

This is how I do it:

```cs
[Route("/template/{Id}","GET")]
public class SingleTemplate : IReturn<Template>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public Template Get(SingleTemplate request)
{
    return Db.LoadSingleById<Template>(request.Id); 
}
```

With all the new AutoQuery and AutoCRUD, it seems to me that the "return a single item by its URL" could also be automatic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, All [AutoQuery](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery) `QueryDb<T>` services return the same fixed [QueryResponse Response DTO](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/cae6c6a64923c227f1a9570099563ef720725e90/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/IQuery.cs#L292-L311) as per its [Service Contract](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/cae6c6a64923c227f1a9570099563ef720725e90/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/IQuery.cs#L279-L280), i.e:

```
public abstract class QueryDb<T> 
    : QueryBase, IQueryDb<T>, IReturn<QueryResponse<T>> { }

public abstract class QueryDb<From, Into> 
    : QueryBase, IQueryDb<From, Into>, IReturn<QueryResponse<Into>> { }

public class QueryResponse<T> : IQueryResponse
{
    public virtual int Offset { get; set; }
    public virtual int Total { get; set; }
    public virtual List<T> Results { get; set; }
    public virtual Dictionary<string, string> Meta { get; set; }
    public virtual ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}
```

A single result would still populate the `Results` property, so the JSON wire format would look like:

```
{ "results":[ {/*Template*/} ] }
```

You could create your own [Custom AutoQuery Implementation](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#custom-autoquery-implementations) that utilizes AutoQuery's `IAutoQueryDb` API to return your own custom populated DTO but then your Request DTO should **NOT** inherit from `QueryDb<T>` as not returning a `QueryResponse<T>` would break the explicit Service contract of the Request DTO (and all clients expecting it), i.e. you would instead just create a normal ServiceStack Service returning your own custom Response Type.

Comment: Is AutoQuery bound to OrmLite?

Comment: @labilbe Yes, it’s only possible because of our full control over OrmLite.